# Python get two value difference and their remaining percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

In python i have a two variable like :

```
toatalCount = 4
completedCount = 2
```

what i actually want is i want 50 as a result what i am getting through this .

```
formula = 100/(toatalCount - completedCount)
```

but when i am having values like:

```
toatalCount = 1
completedCount = 0

or 
toatalCount = 0
completedCount = 1
```

it is not working in that case i want only remaining percentage of variables.Please help me related this i am stuck here

Comment: if you are talking about percentage, you have to divide by total amount. I don't know why you didn't do that. Furthermore, I don't understand why you put (total...-completed...) in the denominator. I think the reasonable way is this: `formula = ( (toatalCount - completedCount) / totalCount ) * 100` 
`

Comment: @Pankhuri, are you sure your formula for percentage is correct?

Comment: i am ussing this formula in some cases it is working fine and in some case it is not working like when value 1 and 0 in variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you have stated in your answer is incorrect. That is the reason your code malfunctions.
You are basically converting a fraction(`completedcount/totalcount`) into percentage.

The correct formula for doing so is:

```
completedcount
——————————     * 100
totalcount
```

if you dislike that method, there is another way for doing this. Convert it to decimal with this:
`completecount/totalcount`

Then multiply that by hundred.

In short, your code is correct but your formula isn't.

How to convert fractions to percentage:

1. [https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/converting-fractions-to-percent#:~:text=Remember%20that%20a%20percent%20is,multiply%20the%20decimal%20by%20100%20](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/converting-fractions-to-percent#:%7E:text=Remember%20that%20a%20percent%20is,multiply%20the%20decimal%20by%20100%20).
2. https://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-fractions-percents.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want the output as the percentage of the two variables. But if toatalCount = 0 then how completedCount = 1 ?? I dont know . your logic is inconsistent. However heres a formula:

```
toatalCount = 4
completedCount = 2

percentage = ((toatalCount - completedCount)/toatalCount) * 100

print(percentage)
```

If you still have any question, then leave a comment.. :)